# Flags in custom maven archetypes

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

When creating a custom maven-archetype, is it possbile to create a flag, for example `hasDependencyX` and make some kind of if-statement to only include the dependency in the `pom.xml` if this specific flag is set to true?